# C++/CLI Converting from System::String^ to std::string

Tags: string, c++-cli, managed-c++

Can someone please post a simple code that would convert,

```
System::String^
```

To,

C++ `std::string`

I.e., I just want to assign the value of,

```
String^ originalString;
```

To,

```
std::string newString;
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Check out `System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToCoTaskMemUni()` and its friends.

*Sorry can't post code now; I don't have VS on this machine to check it compiles before posting.*

Answer (score 186):

Don't roll your own, use [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx) handy (and extensible) wrappers provided by Microsoft.

For example:

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

System::String^ managed = "test";
std::string unmanaged = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(managed);
```

Comment: thx for this useful link, this hint saved me a lot of coding. as a side note: the templates/classes are in #include <msclr\\*.h> (e.g. #include <msclr\marshal.h>) and in the msclr::interop namespace, see an example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/bb384859(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: While this is convenient it totally lacks proper encoding support. See also my SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894551/string-marshalling-with-marshal-as-and-encodings. My assumption is that marshal_as converts Unicode strings to the ACP in std::string.

Comment: MS Recommendation is to use marshal_context and delete it after conversion has been done. The link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384856.aspx

Answer (score 42):

You can easily do this as follows

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

System::String^ xyz="Hi boys"; 

std::string converted_xyz=msclr::interop::marshal_as< std::string >( xyz);
```

Comment: +1 for a short and simple solution and simple working example (although there's an extra parenthesis at the end of your code)

Comment: This is the only solution that directly answers the question.

Comment: hmm... 33 upvotes for an answer that was already given more than 2 years earlier with nearly the same lines of code. respect for gaining so many points for that. ;-)

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
//..
using namespace msclr::interop;
//..
System::String^ clrString = (TextoDeBoton);
std::string stdString = marshal_as<std::string>(clrString); //String^ to std
//System::String^ myString = marshal_as<System::String^>(MyBasicStirng); //std to String^
prueba.CopyInfo(stdString); //MyMethod
//..
//Where: String^ = TextoDeBoton;
//and stdString is a "normal" string;
```

Comment: English translation: "I'm going to respond to this post also :p. This is my function."

Answer (score 9):

Here are some conversion routines I wrote many years ago for a c++/cli project, they *should* still work.

```
void StringToStlWString ( System::String const^ s, std::wstring& os)
    {
        String^ string = const_cast<String^>(s);
        const wchar_t* chars = reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>((Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(string)).ToPointer());
        os = chars;
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));

    }
    System::String^ StlWStringToString (std::wstring const& os) {
        String^ str = gcnew String(os.c_str());
        //String^ str = gcnew String("");
        return str;
    }

    System::String^ WPtrToString(wchar_t const* pData, int length) {
        if (length == 0) {
            //use null termination
            length = wcslen(pData);
            if (length == 0) {
                System::String^ ret = "";
                return ret;
            }
        }

        System::IntPtr bfr = System::IntPtr(const_cast<wchar_t*>(pData));
        System::String^ ret = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringUni(bfr, length);
        return ret;
    }

    void Utf8ToStlWString(char const* pUtfString, std::wstring& stlString) {
        //wchar_t* pString;
        MAKE_WIDEPTR_FROMUTF8(pString, pUtfString);
        stlString = pString;
    }

    void Utf8ToStlWStringN(char const* pUtfString, std::wstring& stlString, ULONG length) {
        //wchar_t* pString;
        MAKE_WIDEPTR_FROMUTF8N(pString, pUtfString, length);
        stlString = pString;
    }
```

Comment: @alap, Use **System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal** or write **using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;**.

Answer (score 7):

I found an easy way to get a std::string from a String^ is to use sprintf().

```
char cStr[50] = { 0 };
String^ clrString = "Hello";
if (clrString->Length < sizeof(cStr))
  sprintf(cStr, "%s", clrString);
std::string stlString(cStr);
```

No need to call the Marshal functions!

**UPDATE** Thanks to Eric, I've modified the sample code to check for the size of the input string to prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: It's a curious decision to introduce a buffer overflow vulnerability in your code just to avoid calling functions specially designed to marshall strings.

Comment: I'm simply presenting a different approach if someone doesn't want to use the marshal functions. I've added a check for the size to prevent overflow.

Comment: @Eric Internally it is marshalling for you. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11831686/1516125) for details. If you check for the size beforehand, you won't have any overflow issues and the code is much cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

I spent hours trying to convert a windows form listbox ToString value to a standard string so that I could use it with fstream to output to a txt file. My Visual Studio didn't come with marshal header files which several answers I found said to use. After so much trial and error I finally found a solution to the problem that just uses System::Runtime::InteropServices:

```
void MarshalString ( String ^ s, string& os ) {
   using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
   const char* chars = 
      (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
   os = chars;
   Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
}

//this is the code to use the function:
scheduleBox->SetSelected(0,true);
string a = "test";
String ^ c = gcnew String(scheduleBox->SelectedItem->ToString());
MarshalString(c, a);
filestream << a;
```

And here is the MSDN page with the example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b4az623(v=vs.80).aspx

I know it's a pretty simple solution but this took me HOURS of troubleshooting and visiting several forums to finally find something that worked.

Answer (score 4):

C# uses the UTF16 format for its strings.
So, besides just converting the types, you should also be conscious about the string's actual format.

When compiling for **Multi-byte Character set** Visual Studio and the Win API assumes UTF8 (Actually windows encoding which is [Windows-28591](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) ).
When compiling for **Unicode Character set** Visual studio and the Win API assume UTF16.

So, you must convert the string from UTF16 to UTF8 format as well, and not just convert to std::string.
This will become necessary when working with multi-character formats like some non-latin languages.

The idea is to decide that `std::wstring` **always** represents **UTF16**.
And `std::string` **always** represents **UTF8**.

This isn't enforced by the compiler, it's more of a good policy to have.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    System::String^ managedString = "test";

    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;

    //Actual format is UTF16, so represent as wstring
    std::wstring utf16NativeString = context.marshal_as<std::wstring>(managedString); 

    //C++11 format converter
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;

    //convert to UTF8 and std::string
    std::string utf8NativeString = convert.to_bytes(utf16NativeString);

    return 0;
}
```

Or have it in a more compact syntax:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    System::String^ managedString = "test";

    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;

    std::string utf8NativeString = convert.to_bytes(context.marshal_as<std::wstring>(managedString));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just want to emphasize the importance of converting to UTF8 in my use case: I needed to pass a file path received from Win32 OpenFileDialog (where file names with multibyte characters are possible, e.g. file names containing Asian characters) to engine code via a std::string, so the conversion to UTF8 was vital. Thanks for the excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

I like to stay away from the marshaller.

```
Using CString newString(originalString);
```

Seems much cleaner and faster to me. No need to worry about creating and deleting a context.

Answer (score 0):

// I used VS2012 to write below code-- convert_system_string to Standard_Sting

```
        #include "stdafx.h"
        #include <iostream>
        #include <string> 

        using namespace System;
        using namespace Runtime::InteropServices; 


        void MarshalString ( String^ s, std::string& outputstring )
        {  
           const char* kPtoC =  (const char*) (Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();                                                        
           outputstring = kPtoC;  
           Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)kPtoC));  
        }   

        int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
        {
             std::string strNativeString;  
             String ^ strManagedString = "Temp";

             MarshalString(strManagedString, strNativeString);  
             std::cout << strNativeString << std::endl; 

             return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was getting an error with some of these messages. I have an std::string. To convert it to String^, I had to do the following `String^ sysString = gcnew String(stdStr.c_str());` where sysString is a System::String^ and stdStr is an std::string. Hope this helps someone

You may have to `#include <string>` for this to work