# AccessViolation, when calling C++-DLL from C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, access-violation

I've written a C++/CLI wrapper for a C++-DLL to use this DLL in a C# programm.

However, when I call a function, which takes a char* I get a AccessViolation

```
int Wrapper::Net_methodX(int a, String^ key, long v)
{
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(key);
    pin_ptr<char> cKey = static_cast<char*>(ptr.ToPointer());
    int val = methodX(a,cKey, v); // AccessViolation here

    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return val;
}
```

The signature of the C++-function is

```
int methodX(int a, char *Key, long v);
```

**EDIT 1**

Just to "pin" like the following didn't work either:

```
int Wrapper::Net_methodX(int a, String^ key, long v)
{
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(key);
    char* cKey = static_cast<char*>(ptr.ToPointer());
    pin_ptr<char> pinned = cKey;
    int val = methodX(a,cKey, v);

    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return val;
}
```

**EDIT 1 END**

**EDIT 2**

I tried also PtrToStringChars the following way (Thanks Matt, found also some doc [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1ae6tz5%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)):

```
int Wrapper::Net_methodX(int a, String^ key, long v)
{
    pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wkey = PtrToStringChars(key);

    size_t convertedChars = 0;
    size_t  sizeInBytes = ((key->Length + 1) * 2);
    errno_t err = 0;
    char * ckey = (char * ) malloc(sizeInBytes);

    err = wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, ckey, sizeInBytes, wkey, sizeInBytes);

    int val = methodX(A_Symbol_Table,ckey, Value);

    return val;
}
```

AccessViolation still occurs, maybe it's an error in methodX() (which is a Third-party-DLL).

**EDIT 2 END**

I have read some related questions here, but did not find a solution yet.

Any hints?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon,
I tried out your example and I do not get an Access Violation.  Here's my code:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

ref class Wrapper
{
public:
    static int Net_methodX(int a, String^ key, long v);
};

int methodX(int a, char * pKey, long v)
{
    IntPtr ptr = static_cast<IntPtr>(pKey);
    String ^ pString = Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi(ptr);
    System::Console::WriteLine(pString);
    return a;
}

int Wrapper::Net_methodX(int a, String^ pKey, long v)
{     
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(pKey);     
    pin_ptr<char> cKey = static_cast<char*>(ptr.ToPointer());     
    int val = methodX(a,cKey, v); // AccessViolation here      
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(ptr);     
    return val; 
}

void main()
{
    Wrapper wrapper;
    String ^ p = gcnew String("Hello");
    wrapper.Net_methodX(0, p, 0);
}
```

Also, I have a few comments:

1. Read here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311259
2. You are using a pin_ptr to native memory.  The StringToHGlobalAnsi method returns native memory, so I don't think using a pin_ptr makes sense here.  A pin_ptr would make sense if you were using a method that gives you back a pointer to managed memory (like PtrToStringChars).  Unless you are modifying the string, you probably want to go with the PtrToStringChars approach anyways--to avoid unnecessary allocation and copying.
3. Would you post an example version of methodX that causes the problem?  If I can reproduce the issue, I might be able to be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification at 2. I tried to use PtrToStringChars (see Edit 2 in my original posting), but the AccessViolation still occurs. Unfortunately methodX() is from a Third-party-DLL, so no source code and only poor documentation. I just get a trace, that the method has been entered with the values of a, key, and v.

Comment: To eliminate the possibility that methodX is the problem, have you tried passing in a natively allocated char * (actually, it looks like your edit 2 tries this out)? If you're getting a TRACE that the method has been entered, then I'd suspect methodX is the culprit (or you are passing it something it doesn't expect).

Comment: Yes, I assume the problem is in methodX as well. I just wanted to make sure, there's no error in the wrapper. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone who stumble upon this question looking for an answer, here are some simpler solutions.

1. Simply use `sprintf` to do the conversion like this: `sprintf(cStr, "%s", clrString);`. See [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946813/c-cli-converting-from-systemstring-to-stdstring/28333179#28333179) for a complete example.
2. Read [KB311259](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311259) as suggested by Matt Smith. If you are using VS 2008 or higher, use `marshal_as<>` (Method #4 in the KB). It's much simpler than the other methods in that document.

Comment: Had this same issue just now. `marshal_as<const char*>` ended up working beautifully for me, where I was previously having trouble with `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi`.

Answer (score 0):

Simon

I think there is a problem with the following code

```
pin_ptr<char> cKey = static_cast<char*>(ptr.ToPointer());
```

You might want to read this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/0bd049fe-844a-4cb6-b9f6-c8f5107bc957

Let me know if it helped you.

Sujay

Comment: As suggested in the link, I tried just to "pin" cKey to avoid GC and passed a char* to the C++-function. But the AccessViolation still occurs.