# How to build Echoprint Codegen for a C# application?

Tags: c#, dll, cmake, c++-cli, command-line-interface

I am trying to build https://github.com/echonest/echoprint-codegen in a way that would allow me to reference it from a C# project.  I have followed their build instructions and have ran into various issues with CMake not being able to build the project or even the dependencies.  I have also tried to make it CLI based which led me to [C++/CLI noob: System.AccessViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249237/c-cli-noob-system-accessviolationexception/23702768#23702768) at which point I decided to try the answer there and utilize the DLLs that https://stackoverflow.com/users/259059/floele linked.  I cannot get those to be referenced/used from my project (error message about not being a valid assembly or COM DLL).
TLDR: I am trying to get the echoprint fingerprint of a music file and am having difficulties getting the project to be built/referenced from my C# code.

Comment: This is a very general question. If you want to have a specific answer, I think you need to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to work with C++ code from C#. Some of the options you have are:

- Write a C wrapper for the C++ library and PInvoke it.
- Write a C++/CLI wrapper for the C++ library and call that.
- Use [Mono CppSharp](https://github.com/mono/CppSharp).

Answer (score 0):

I just ported the echoprint-codegen to C# and called it EchoPrintSharp. The PCL is available via [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EchoPrintSharp/) and the source is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Thomas-Mielke-Software/EchoPrintSharp).

Nuget PCL:

```
Install-Package EchoPrintSharp
```

or .NET Standard:

```
Install-Package EchoPrintSharp.Netstandard
```