# ofstream issue in Visual C++ 2010 regarding Strings

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to create a Windows Forms Application in Visual C++ 2010. I have saved some particular string in string variable "stat" like:

```
System::String ^stat = "sample string";
```

The problem is, I cannot write it to a text file using ofstream. When I try this:

```
if ( opstat == true ) // opstat is a bool variable
{
    ofstream outf("mytxt.txt",ios::app);
    outf << stat;
    outf.close();
}
```

Compiler returns an error:

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'System::String ^' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

And a huge error that goes on forever like:

```
1>          D:\Development\Visual Studio 2010\VC\include\ostream(447): or 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator <<(long double)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
```

What am I supposed to do here?

P.S. I have already included all necessary headers (or the ones I think are necessary) like string, fstream, istream, iomanip etc.

Comment: Hmm, I assume you are using std::ostream?
So what exactly is System::String?
The problem seems to be that there is no "<<" operator defined in std::ostream with your "System::String" as second operand, whereas with "std::String" it would work.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between [c++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) and [c++/cli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_CLI)?  I ask because you tagged with the former, but this code is the latter.

Comment: @user905686: `System::String` refers to the .NET String class I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to convert `System::String ^stat` to `std::string`. See below link how to convert:

[C++/CLI Converting from System::String^ to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946813/c-cli-converting-from-systemstring-to-stdstring)

Comment: After learning how to convert `System::String` to `std::string`, perhaps as an exercise, implement a stream inserter that allows for type `System::String^`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::ofstream` is an C++ Standard Library function, and it's not built to support `System::String^`. If you want to write to a file from a `System::String^`, you should use the `System::IO::FileStream` class. Otherwise, use a `std::string` instead of `System::String^`.

Comment: `ofstream` is not, and never was part of the STL.  The term is "The C++ Standard Library", and that also covers the parts that actually did originally come from the STL.