# How to write a variable in to file in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli

I have a program in C++/CLI. I need to write my text and variable to file.

My code:

```cpp
String^ MyVariable;
MyVariable = folderBrowserDialog1->SelectedPath // C://User/Users

std::ofstream out;
out.open("hello.txt");
if (out.is_open())
{
  out << "Variable: " << MyVariable << std::endl; // ERROR
}
out.close();
```

How to fix error?

Comment: What is `MyVariable`? What is the error message? Please provide [mcve].

Comment: What error? Please add a piece of code that we can (try to) compile and see the same error as you do. Where are the includes, `int main`, the declaration of `MyVariable`?... Also add the entire error message too.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8565889/1387438 (already used my vote to "Debuging details").

Comment: You cannot use c++ `std::ofstream` with c++/cli `System::String`. But you can convert it to `std::string` (which is compatible with `std::ofstream`) with the info in the link above.

Comment: Ok, but i can write txt or cfg file in c++/cli?

Comment: You can use c++/cli (i.e. .NET) file I/O APIs with `System::String`, but not native c++ APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++/CLI is a different language than C++.
It actually belong to the .NET family of languages and is meant to bridge .NET to native c++ code.

You cannot use `std::ofstream` (which is a native C++ class) directly with `System::String` (which is a C++/CLI i.e. .NET class).

You have 2 options:

1. Convert the `System::String` (.NET) to `std::string` (native C++). This is demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946813/c-cli-converting-from-systemstring-to-stdstring). After the conversion you can write it to the file using `std::ofstream` as you attempted.
2. Use .NET APIs for writing the file, for example with `FileStream` and `StreamWriter`, as demonstrated below:

   ```
   System::String^ MyVariable = gcnew System::String("abc");

   System::IO::FileStream^ fs = System::IO::File::Create("hello.txt");
   System::IO::StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew System::IO::StreamWriter(fs);

   sw->WriteLine("Variable: " + MyVariable);

   sw->Close();
   ```

   The content of the file will be:

   ```
   Variable: abc
   ```