# writing printf data to a string variable in c++/cli

Tags: c++, string, c++-cli

I need to send a fomatted data to a tcp ip port in my c++/cli program.I have this code with no success

```
String^ data;
sprintf(data,"L,%02u%02u%02u%02u%02u%02u%03u,%lf %lf\n",rDateTime.uiYear, rDateTime.usiMonth, rDateTime.usiDay,
                rDateTime.usiHour, rDateTime.usiMinute, rDateTime.usiSec, 
                rDateTime.udiUSec / 1000,container[i].first,container[i].second);
```

I get the error *error C2664: 'sprintf' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::String ^' to char **

I want to write it to a string variable **std::string**.

Can someone provide with some suggestions.If atleast I convert it to **System::String^**. I can convert it to the std:string using this [C++/CLI Converting from System::String^ to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946813/c-cli-converting-from-systemstring-to-stdstring). But I dont know how to write the different datatypes to a string^ in c++/cli..

Comment: `sprintf` would probably be what you're looking for if it's there in cli.

Comment: Have you considered System::String::Format?

Comment: @chris.. I tried that before and i edited my question accordingly

Comment: sprintf() is a native C library function, it requires a char[] as the first argument.  A System::String is not a char[].  Either use a char[] and convert to String or use String::Format().  You ought to get up to speed on composite string formatting if you plan to write more C++/CLI code.

Comment: @HansPassant Can I give some sample example code. I am just beginning my steps in c++/cli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare a temperory variable with type `char*`.  I am using a fixed array here for demonstration purpose.  Since you may have a long string, I suggest you to look at [_snprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93%28VS.80%29.aspx) to avoid buffer overflow error.

After you get your string in `char*`, you can create a managed `System::String` using `gcnew`

```
char str[1024];

sprintf(str,"L,%02u%02u%02u%02u%02u%02u%03u,%lf %lf\n",rDateTime.uiYear, rDateTime.usiMonth, rDateTime.usiDay, 
            rDateTime.usiHour, rDateTime.usiMinute, rDateTime.usiSec,  
            rDateTime.udiUSec / 1000,container[i].first,container[i].second); 

System::String^ data = gcnew System::String(str); 
Console::WriteLine(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [sprintf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) function takes a char array (`char *`) as it's first argument. If you want to use it in this way, you need to first write into a char array, and then convert it into a string.
I don't know about `System::String^`, but you can convert a char array into an `std::string` by a simple assigning like this:

```
char * data = new char[50];
sprintf(data, "Your text goes here");
std::string str = data;
```

Don't forget to allocate memory for the char array! if you forget it and write something like this:

```
char * data;
sprintf(data, "Your text goes here");
```

you are going to get an error. 
On the other hand, if std::string is suitable for you, you can format it directly using [formatting manipulators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/)

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is Not The Way To Do It if you are writing new managed code, but if you are porting unmanaged legacy C++ code that works with `printf` and `const char*`, there is no reason to rewrite the whole thing Just To Be Right.

This works for me and should safely work for any size string. I use it to wrap some functions that call Trace(...) to give flexibility of having a delegated Action deal with logging messages.

```
void TraceBase1(const char* prefix, const char* format, va_list argp) {
  if (Logger::m_logDelegate != nullptr) {

    System::String^ message;

    int count = _vscprintf(format,argp) + 1;
    char* buffer = new char[count ];
    try {
        _vsnprintf(buffer,count,format,argp);
        message =  gcnew System::String(buffer);
        Logger::m_logDelegate(message);
    }
    finally {
        delete[] buffer;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at how [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) works on your platform?