# Convert System::String^ (C# string) to C++ std::string

Tags: c#, c++, string, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++/CLI Converting from System::String^ to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946813/c-cli-converting-from-systemstring-to-stdstring)

I am using a C# DLL in my C++ code (Visual Studio 2010). How do I convert a System::String^ to a C++ std::string?

Answer (score 0):

[`System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal_members%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) has several methods that convert a string to an array of characters, which you could then use any manner of methods to get a `std::string`.

I believe the recommendation is to use [`StringToBSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtobstr%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) eventually calling `FreeBSTR` once you have copied the data to a different object.

The question I linked to as a comment recommends `StringToCoTaskMemUni`.