# Passing String^ to sql command

Tags: c++-cli

I'm working on c++/cli window form I want to get string from textBox and bring them to be part of sql command ( I use mysql.h ) but I can't combine this string with normal string.

And I try to make String^ as sql command but it can't pass String^ to query function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the string^ is a .net string type and must be converted to a native string.  Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946813/c-cli-converting-from-systemstring-to-stdstring) for the answer.