# Pull the strings from a managed Listbox to a class variable of type char*

Tags: c++, string, pointers, listbox, char

This is confusing. I understand pointers but what is with tracking references? 

The instructions are not very clear on what to do even on the wiki, not to mention I was never taught this in adv C++. So, How do I get the items in a listbox into one of my classes?

Also is can i get a brief rundown of tracking references for future reference?

My form has a Listbox called listbox2 with some data in it.

My class called "ManifistOBJ" has a method called "setFilename(char*)"

Now in other programs i can easily add objects to the "AddFilename" method but how do i do it for a tracking reference?

Sofar iv tried:

```
DMManifest newmanifest = DMManifest();
         for(int i =1;i< listBox2->Items->Count;i++)
         {
             ManifistOBJ newobj = ManifistOBJ();
             System::String^ temp = listBox2->Items[i]->ToString();
             String temp1 = temp;//?
             char* temp2 = temp1.c_str();
             newobj.setFilename(temp2);
             newmanifest.push_back(newobj);
         }
```

With that ^ next to string I cant DE-reference it. and I have no idea how to.
I could make the method take a string^ but that would mess up my other programs that use that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

System::String^ temp = listBox2->Items[i]->ToString(); 

std::string temp1 = msclr::interop::marshal_as< std::string >( temp );
```

[C++/CLI Converting from System::String^ to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946813/c-cli-converting-from-systemstring-to-stdstring)