# error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'System::String ^' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: .net, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli, native

I have a problem similiar to some that was already solved here, but there is one more thing I cannot fix.
I am using VS 2013.
The code is:

```
std::ofstream list("filename.txt", std::ios::app);
list << textBox1->Text << std::endl;
```

I do not know what to do with this. If I add std:: to 'list << ...' it says that 'list' is not part of std.
Headers: iostream, fstream, string.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You are using C++ file IO and C++/CLI with .Net UI code. Other than marshalling as a possibility, **just use .Net file IO instead of C++ file IO** (C++/CLI is great for wrapping C or C++ code for use with other .Net Languages, but otherwise I would not recommend it and would suggest using C# instead if you want to use .Net for an application with UI).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing CLI code with native code. The Text property has to be marshalled.
[See answers of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946813/c-cli-converting-from-systemstring-to-stdstring)

Comment: It would be better and simpler to just use .NET IO instead of `std` IO and marshaling.