# Convert Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<String^>^ to std::string

Tags: c++-cli

I have a Windows Universal C++ App with a WebView, which is calling a Javascript function that returns a string. Now I want to convert a `Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<String^>^` to an `std::string`

Here is the code that calls the Javascript function

```
Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<String^>^ result = this->webView1->InvokeScriptAsync("JSfunction", arguments);
```

I'd like to have `result` as a `std::string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is not of type `String^`,  it is `IAsyncOperation<String^>`, an asynchronous operation that *will* return a String^ to its caller.

To get the result of type `String^`, call the `GetResults` method on the IAsyncOperation.

```
String^ result = this->webView1->InvokeScriptAsync("JSfunction", arguments)->GetResults();
```

Then you can convert String^ to std::string following [Q: C++/CLI Converting from System::String^ to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946813).