# Convert from System::String^ to System::String

Tags: c++, managed-c++

I have a standard library string, and I would like to make the following conversion:

System::String^ to std::string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++/CLI Converting from System::String^ to std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946813/c-cli-converting-from-systemstring-to-stdstring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code fragment to convert `std::string` to `System::String^`:

```
#include <msclr/marshal.h>

std::string str = "Hello World";
System::String^ result = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(str.c_str());
```

Code fragment to convert `System::String^` to `std::string`:

```
#include <msclr/marshal.h>

System::String^ str = "Hello World";
std::string result = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(str);
```