# How to convert OpenFileDialog file path to ifstream path in C++

Tags: c++, header

I have a simple C++ GUI base program that select the file using `OpenFileDialog` property. I need to get the file path and then I need to use that file path to read the text file line by line using `getline()`. But it gives an error when I replace the `ifstream` variable value as `OpenFileDialog` value. My code is attached below.

I want to replace

```
ifstream myfile("C:/Users/Shenal/Desktop/source.vandii");
```

with

```
ifstream myfile(strfilename);
```

The code is down below.

my ***form1.h*** file

```
Stream^ mystream;
OpenFileDialog^ OpenFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

String^ strfilename = OpenFileDialog1->InitialDirectory + OpenFileDialog1->FileName;

String^ Readfile = File::ReadAllText(strfilename);

//MessageBox::Show(Readfile);

string line;
ifstream myfile("C:/Users/Shenal/Desktop/source.vandii");
ofstream compiledFile;
vector<string> filecontent;

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    MessageBox::Show(Readfile);
    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
        getline(myfile, line);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/946813/c-cli-converting-from-systemstring-to-stdstring

Comment: `OpenFileDialog^`...`Stream^` -- This is not C++, but cli.

Comment: @parktomatomi this is working. Thank you.

Comment: On a side note, see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/)